# If $f(x)= \int_0^{\ln x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4+e^t}},$ find $(f^{-1})'(0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

For $$f(x)= \int_0^{\ln x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4+e^t}}\, dt,\quad  x>0,$$ find $(f^{-1})'(0)$

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus? Use this to compute $f'$, and then relate $f'$ and $(f^{-1})'$.

Comment: I am familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I'm not very good at using it. I'll give it a try though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT :**
$$ f (x)=\int^{\ln x}_0\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {4+e^t}} dt $$
Thus, by the F.T.C,
$$ f^{'}=\dfrac {1}{x\sqrt {4+x}}$$
Since
$$(f^{-1})^{'}(x)=\dfrac {1}{f^{'}(f^{-1}(x))} $$
 We have
$$(f^{-1})^{'}(0)=x\sqrt {4+ f^{-1}(0)} $$

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint! I think I'll be able to solve it now.